# I don't know how to approach this question!

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

[Click here to see my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQuXh.png)

How do I eliminate the vector product to solve the differential equation as in the above question (Click the link to see the question)

Comment: Try splitting your initial equation into three equations, one describing $x(t)$, one describing $y(t)$ and one describing $z(t)$. The latter should be simply $\frac{d^2 z}{dt^2} = 0$.

Comment: But wouldn't there still be a vector in the equation even if I were to write the equation in terms of x(t) and y(t)? How do I deal with that?

Comment: No, there wouldn't be. There are really three left-hand-side terms, as $\vec{r} = ( x, y, z)$; write the right-hand-side equation for each of them. No vectors should remain.

Comment: I am sorry if I am sounding dumb but I would really appreciate to know how the vector gets eliminated so that I can proceed to solve the ordinary differential equation that would result from it. I have been at this question for an hour and I have another hour to submit it for my test! I would really appreciate it if you would help me out!

Answer (score 0):

$\vec r = (x,y,z)\\
\vec E = (E,0,0)\\
\vec H = (0,0,H)$

We have the diff eq.

$m\frac {d^2r}{dt^2} = e\vec E - \frac {e}{c}\left(\frac {dr}{dt}\times \vec H\right)$

Substitute with the vectors above.

$m(x'',y'', z'') = e(E,0,0) - \frac {e}{c}\left((x',y',z')\times (0,0,H)\right)$

Calculate the cross product.

$m(x'',y'', z'') = e(E,0,0) - \frac {e}{c}(Hy', -Hx', 0)$

Add the components together

$(mx'',my'', mz'') = (eE + \frac {e}{c}Hy', -\frac {e}{c}Hx', 0)$

If the LHS equals the RHS, each component of the respective vectors are equal

$mx'' = eE + \frac {e}{c}Hy'\\
my'' = -\frac {e}{c}Hx'\\
mz'' = 0$

Does that get you started?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I finally get this! You saved my test, I appreciate it a lot! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: I ended up messing up the solution of these differential equations. I tried to eliminate x by multiplying required terms in the two equations and ended up with something of the likes of a/(bD+c(D^3)), with a, b, c representing those bulky constant terms, and somehow messed it up and did not reach the answer. thus, my test got ruined. I also tried using laplace but that led to even bulkier terms. What did i miss?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could help me solve those differential equations or point out the method i should use to solve them.

Comment: $y''' = -\frac {e}{c}H x'' = -\frac {e}{c} H (eE  + \frac ec H y') \implies y' = A\sin (\frac {e}{c}H t) + B \cos (\frac {e}{c}H t) - \frac {e^2}{c}E$